# Creating multiplatform installer based on command line one

Tags: linux, windows, macos, qt, installation

**Description**

We've are open sourcing several applications (both GUI and cmd based) and want to create graphical installer for them. We've already have a dedicated command line toolkit – providing installation / uninstallation / parallel installed versions switching / etc functionalities (something similar to `nvm`).

**Requirements**

1. The graphical installer should NOT incorporate any logic – it will be just used to gather installation parameters and pass them to the command line toolkit, including:

   - Selecting a component(s) to be installed
   - Choosing version of selected components
   - Selecting paths of the installation
2. The graphical installer should be dynamically configured from the command line toolkit – all the information like available components / their versions / default installation paths / etc. will be provided by the cmd tool.
3. The GUI should be able to display progress bar while downloading components (our cmd toolkit behaves like online installer and provides real-time information about the status of download).
4. The graphical installer should work on major OS (Linux, MacOs, Windows) + other highly welcome.
5. We would love the installer to be light-weight and do not depend on any third-party libraries that the end-user would have to provide (like python) – we want to provide just an executable that can be "double clicked" after the download. This also means that installer executable have to incorporate our cmd tool (which is just a binary program, written in Haskell).
6. We would love to provide as native look as possible, however this is not a "must have" feature.

**Not yet working solution propositions**

We were thinking about 2 solutions so far:

1. Using QT Installer Framework, however it seems like it is designed as a complete solution and using it just as a GUI to gather information could be either cumbersome or not possible taking in consideration limited configuration options (I could however be wrong here and if it will appear that it is easy to do what we want using this framework, I will be very happy).
2. Creating our own installer GUI from scratch, but we would rather do not want to do it and maintain it IF there are any standard tools that could be utilized.